# R: Goodness of fit with logitfmx

Tags: r, logistic-regression, effects, goodness-of-fit

I estimated some binary logistic models with marginal effects using the `mfx` package in R `logitmfx()`. Now I need the goodness of fit e.g. Nagelkerke R^2.
Using the `NagelkerkeR2()` of the `fmsb` package returns the error:

> "Error in -rr$null : invalid argument to unary operator"

How can I get a goodness of fit for my models?

Thanks!